# Error:Could not find installable ISAM

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-access

i got this error whenever i trying execute my project which is used database "msaccess".
the error is like this

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find installable ISAM.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Could not find installable ISAM.

Source Error: 


Line 148:       // open DB Connection via OleDb
Line 149:       Connection = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
Line 150:       Connection.Open();
Line 151:       
Line 152:   }

Source File: D:\excelsior\.Net Applications\TDAPP8-Web_Based_Bug_tracking_system\Web based Bug Tracking System\BugTrackingNew\BugTrackingNew\CCUtility.cs    Line: 150 

Stack Trace: 


[OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not find installable ISAM.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) +968297
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +86
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +29
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +4861516
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() +40
   Bug_Management.CCUtility.DBOpen() in D:\excelsior\.Net Applications\TDAPP8-Web_Based_Bug_tracking_system\Web based Bug Tracking System\BugTrackingNew\BugTrackingNew\CCUtility.cs:150
   Bug_Management.CCUtility..ctor(Object parent) in D:\excelsior\.Net Applications\TDAPP8-Web_Based_Bug_tracking_system\Web based Bug Tracking System\BugTrackingNew\BugTrackingNew\CCUtility.cs:80
   Bug_Management.ProjectMaint1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\excelsior\.Net Applications\TDAPP8-Web_Based_Bug_tracking_system\Web based Bug Tracking System\BugTrackingNew\BugTrackingNew\ProjectMaint.cs:76
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

**EDIT**

```
<appSettings> <add key="sDBConnectionString" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;datasource=C:\excelsior\.Net Applications\TDAPP8-Web_Based_Bug_tracking_system\Web based Bug Tracking SystemAccessDB.mdb"/> </appSettings>
```

Comment: Please post your connection string.

Comment: sorry i forget.here is my connection string      <appSettings>
        <add key="sDBConnectionString"  value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;datasource=C:\excelsior\.Net Applications\TDAPP8-Web_Based_Bug_tracking_system\Web based Bug Tracking SystemAccessDB.mdb"/>
       
    </appSettings>

Comment: <appSettings>
        <add key="sDBConnectionString"  value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;datasource=C:\excelsior\.Net Applications\TDAPP8-Web_Based_Bug_tracking_system\Web based Bug Tracking SystemAccessDB.mdb"/>
       
    </appSettings>

Comment: That should be `data source` not `datasource` (http://www.connectionstrings.com/access)

Comment: Could not find installable ISAM is typical of a bad connection string, so I think the string should be corrected first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could not find installable ISAM is typical of a bad connection string.

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=C:\excelsior\.Net Applications\TDAPP8-Web_Based_Bug_tracking_system\Web based Bug Tracking SystemAccessDB.mdb"
```

Note data source with a space.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing a space as well and other answers weren't helping!

Comment: Also note that specifying a password, there is a colon (:) not semicolon (;) in between "Jet OLEDB" and "Database Password" --> "Jet OLEDB:Database Password"